# Unity3D declaring vars or using GetComponent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Is it better to either declare var components at the class level or reference them with GetComponent later in code?

example:

```
vitals = GetComponent<Vitals>();
weapon = GetComponent<Weapon>();
```

or should I just use

```
GetComponent<Vitals>.ApplyHealth(25);
```

which is better for performance/memory usage?

Comment: I you plan to use `GetComponent<Vitals>.ApplyHealth(25);` in Update loop, its better to get a reference: `vitals = GetComponent<Vitals>();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing a reference is better for performance, especially if this is done often. Essentially, unity has to perform a lookup to find the component every time you call getcomponent, which can be very expensive and affect performance. If you are accessing this every fupdate, store a reference. If you access it very infrequently, you can get away with looking it up when you need it.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. It's what I thought but wanted to verify.

Comment: stored references are cheap, since they are just references to existant object and not copies. However, be aware that stored references can keep an object alive when it should otherwise get garbage collected, so keeping them around too long may affect memory